# Expose a Rest/JSON Service into my Amazon EC2 VM

Tags: json, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a service running into my Amazon EC2 VM (windows 2012 server)

It's a rest/json service (POST).

I can call from soap UI inside my VM but I'm not able to perform a call from my laptop (internet).

all the inbound/outbound security rules are open.

There is any configuration to expose this service ?

Comment: Is your service bound to an actual IP address or to the loopback 127.0.0.1?

Comment: running on IIS or what?

Comment: Is a Java Rest Service, not running in IIS, I bound it to localhost:7878